# Swift : UIPageControl auto swipe in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

I've ImageView placed inside UICollectionViewCell and a PageControl below it. Both are connected via programmatically.

However, I want `auto swipe (say every 5 seconds) the images should auto swipe.` If user swipe manually then too it should happen. Also, when page control reaches to last it should begin with first.

[image: Screenshot]

Below is code that I've used :

```
 var offersImages: [UIImage] = [     //Array of Banners
        UIImage(named: "default-banner.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "default-banner.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "default-banner.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "default-banner.png")!,
    ]

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.objPageControl.currentPage = 0
        self.objPageControl.numberOfPages = self.offersImages.count
    }

 func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageWidth : CGFloat = self.objBannerCollectionView.frame.size.width
        self.objPageControl.currentPage = Int(self.objBannerCollectionView.contentOffset.x/pageWidth)
    }
```

How can this be done in Swift?

Comment: use NSTimer to control time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code solved my problem :

```
   //MARK:- viewDidLoad
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        . . .

         _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: #selector(moveToNextPage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

     func moveToNextPage (){
        let pageWidth:CGFloat = self.objBannerCollectionView.frame.width
        let maxWidth:CGFloat = pageWidth * 4
        let contentOffset:CGFloat = self.objBannerCollectionView.contentOffset.x

        var slideToX = contentOffset + pageWidth

        if  contentOffset + pageWidth == maxWidth {
                slideToX = 0
        }

        self.objBannerCollectionView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x:slideToX, y:0, width:pageWidth, height:self.objBannerCollectionView.frame.height), animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer following link , it will help to resolve your problem.

[Horizontal Paging](http://sweettutos.com/2015/04/13/how-to-make-a-horizontal-paging-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-storyboards-swift/)